# How to avoid a tkinter window from maximizing?

Tags: python-3.x, tkinter

how to avoid maximizing a tkinter window?

what i have tried:

```
import tkinter as tk
root = tk.Tk()
root.geometry("800x800")


def de_maximize():
    root.geometry("800x800")


root.protocol("WM_MAXIMIZE_WINDOW", de_maximize)
root.mainloop()
```

it didn't work...

```
import tkinter as tk
root = tk.Tk()
root.geometry("800x800")


def de_maximize():
    root.geometry("800x800")


root.attributes("-fullscreen", True)
root.bind("<configure>", de_maximize)  # Throws an Error!
```

Error = _tkinter.TclError: bad event type or keysym "configure"

is there a way to delete the maximize button
is there a way to Handle the maximize event?

Comment: Out of curiosity, why do you want to prevent the user from maximizing the window?

Comment: In the second example,You make it fullscreen.......BTW,it is `<Configure>` not `<configure>`,and in the `de_maximize`,add a arguments(default event).

Comment: Can delete the button for maximizing the window because i really don't want my users to maximize the window ```root.attributes("-fullscreen", True) ``` seems to do ```root.overrideredirect()``` and i really don't prefer that.

Comment: **Can i...** typo